# Removing a certain line inside a generated html code using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have the following generated html code from d3js in my webpage:

```
<path class="line" d="M1161.736,75.2609523809524L580.868,89.75238095238097L0,138.81904761904758L-299342.3078216,138.81904761904758L-299923.1758216,147.04761904761898" style="stroke: rgb(0, 173, 242);"></path>
```

Is there a way I can get rid of the line "L-299342.3078216,138.81904761904758L-299923.1758216,147.04761904761898" using just javascript? I want to remove any numbers that starts with "-"

I have no access to the generated numbers so Im trying to do a hack on js for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the output that you want to achieve? `<path ...></path>`

Comment: @Tân <path class="line" d="M1161.736,75.2609523809524L580.868,89.75238095238097L0,138.81904761904758" style="stroke: rgb(0, 173, 242);"></path>
 or <path class="line" d="M1161.736,75.2609523809524L580.868,89.75238095238097L0,138.81904761904758LL" style="stroke: rgb(0, 173, 242);"></path> . Either way is fine as long as the negative values are removed

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but you might need to modify the regular expression if the pattern changes:

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName("path")[0].getAttribute("d");
d = d.replace(/L-(\d)/g, ""); // Regular expression (assumes 'L-' always at the end of the 'd' element, to be adapted if needed)
document.getElementsByTagName("path")[0].setAttribute("d", d);
```

In case you have multiple 'path' elements, you will need to make a loop over all of them, using something like:

```
var paths = document.getElementsByTagName("path");
for (var index = 0; index < paths.length; index++) {
    d = paths[index].getAttribute("d");
    // etc.
}
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit.**

I have adapted the code to account for all the paths, and the regex as well; I also put `console.log` so you can check if it fits your requirements:

```
var paths = document.getElementsByTagName("path");
for (var index = 0; index < paths.length; index++) {
    d = paths[index].getAttribute("d");
    console.log(d);
    d = d.replace(/L-(.*)$/g, ""); // Regular expression (assumes 'L-' always at the end of the 'd' element, to be adapted if needed)
    document.getElementsByTagName("path")[index].setAttribute("d", d);
    console.log(d);
    console.log("---");
}
```

Comment: Hello, i tried doing it here : https://jsfiddle.net/oq861y2v/ mind checking? It's not working on my end.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this pattern: `([\d.]+)?L-[\d.]+,?`

```js
for (var tag of Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("path"))) {
  var value = tag.getAttribute("d").replace(/([\d.]+)?L-[\d.]+,?/g, "");
  
  tag.setAttribute('d', value);
  
  document.body.innerText += tag.outerHTML
}
```

```html
<path class="line" d="M1161.736,75.2609523809524L580.868,89.75238095238097L0,138.81904761904758L-299342.3078216,138.81904761904758L-299923.1758216,147.04761904761898" style="stroke: rgb(0, 173, 242);"></path>
```

We use `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("path"))` because you may have more than 1 `<path>` tag.

`([\d.]+)?L` means: before `L` character may have a string which contains numbers and some dots.

`L-[\d.]+` means: after `L` character, it's `-` character, numbers and some dots.

`,?` means: `,` character. This character can be matched zero or one time.

Comment: thank you for this, can you check on this? https://jsfiddle.net/oq861y2v/ i am getting a weird output.

Comment: @JustineM The pattern you're using NOT same to mine